# How to display different y labels in the equations using stat_poly_eq of ggpmisc

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I'm trying to display the equations on the plot using the `stat_poly_eq` function of `ggpmisc`.

My problem is how to change the `y= ...` in the equation, by `y1=...` and `y2=...` by referring to the `key` argument.

I tried to add the `eq.with.lhs` argument in the mapping but it does not recognize the argument.
I tried to pass a vector to the `eq.with.lhs` argument but it overlapped both elements in each equation...

Do you have a better idea?

In the last case, I could use `geom_text` after calculating the equation coefficients myself, but it seemed to be a less efficient way to solve the problem.

Here is a reprex of my problem.

```
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20)) %>% 
    mutate(y1 = 1.2*x + rnorm(20, sd=0.2),
           y2 = 0.9*x + rnorm(20, sd=0.3)) %>%
    gather(value = value, key = key, -x)  

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = value)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = key, colour = key)) + 
    stat_poly_eq(aes(label = ..eq.label.., colour = key), 
                 formula = y  ~ poly(x, 1, raw = TRUE),
                 eq.x.rhs = "x",
                 # eq.with.lhs = c(paste0(expression(y[1]), "~`=`~"),
                 #                 paste0(expression(y[2]), "~`=`~")),
                 eq.with.lhs = paste0(expression(y[ind]), "~`=`~"),
                 parse = TRUE) +
    ylab(NULL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure if it's possible to do it through `ggpmisc`, but you can change the data once the plot is built, like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20)) %>% 
    mutate(y1 = 1.2*x + rnorm(20, sd=0.2),
           y2 = 0.9*x + rnorm(20, sd=0.3)) %>%
    gather(value = value, key = key, -x)  

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = value)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = key, colour = key)) + 
    stat_poly_eq(aes(label = ..eq.label.., colour = key), 
                 formula = y  ~ poly(x, 1, raw = TRUE),
                 eq.x.rhs = "x",
                 eq.with.lhs = paste0(expression(y), "~`=`~"),
                 parse = TRUE) +
    ylab(NULL)
temp <- ggplot_build(p)
temp$data[[2]]$label <- temp$data[[2]]$label %>% 
    fct_relabel(~ str_replace(.x, "y", paste0("y[", 1:2, "]")))
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(temp))
```

[image: example]

Comment: Very nice work around!! I didn't new the function ggplot_build to modify elements of the ggplot. Thank you very much ;)